# TRUNC two times divided by 0.20833333333

Tags: sql, oracle

I come from the world of SQL Server, and have been asked to figure out what's going on with a piece of (ancient) Oracle script.

> **CAVEAT**: I don't have access to the Oracle server, I just have the script that someone emailed me, and our copied-over data on SQL Server.
>
> I don't have access to the tasks that have been moving the data from Oracle to SQL Server either. I'm pretty much in the dark -  I have the Oracle script, and (most of) the transformed SQL Server tables.

I'm doing okay interpreting most of it with help from Google, but I can't for the life of me figure out what this is doing:

```
decode(TRUNC((fin_time-start_time)/0.208333333333333),0,1,1,2)
```

I think I've interpreted the `decode` portion correctly equivilent to:

```
case TRUNC((fin_time-start_time)/0.208333333333333)
when 0 then 1
when 1 then 2
end
```

But the TRUNC function is confusing me. `endtime` and `starttime` are times with no date part (eg `16:00:00` or `18:15:00`). Again, without access to or any experience with Oracle, I don't know if this means there's a TIME datatype, or if it's just a DATETIME with a 'default' datestamp (eg `1900-01-01`). In either case, the date is either non-existent or irrelevant.

The documentation would seem to suggest that `TRUNC()` passed with no format parameter will just strip the time part. But the time part is all that the column contains. So the presumably resulting `0` being divided by 0.2083... I'm either on entirely the wrong track, or this is [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/) worthy (or, I suspect, both).

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**: I think I've interpreted it correctly now as:

```
case floor(cast(dateadd(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, START_TIME, FIN_TIME), 0) as float) / 0.2083333333333)
when 0 then 1
when 1 then 2
end
```

Which *does* appear to return expected values, but I think is still a WTF as values other than 0 and 1 are returned, unless I'm interpreting `DECODE()` behaviour incorrectly. I assume for non-covered cases without a default parameter, it would return `NULL` (as `case` does)?

Comment: It should be `... DATEDIFF(day, ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtracting two dates in Oracle returns a number that represents the **number of days**.

Example:

```
SELECT  TO_DATE('03.12.2004 13:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
      - TO_DATE('03.12.2004 01:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
from dual ;
Result: 0.5
```

This expression returns:

- `0`, if the difference between `fin_time` and `start_time` is less than 5 hours,
- `1`, if the difference is greater than or equal to 5 hours but less than 10 hours,
- `null`, otherwise.

Comment: Just a nitpick, exactly 5 hours should also return 1.